# HAProxy stuck on ssl websocket (parse livequery)

Tags: ssl, websocket, haproxy, parse-server

My use-case is use HAProxy as ssl termination on Parse Server & Parse LiveQuery. I'm stuck on haproxy config because it can't connect websocket properly, and it's work only when connect to local (no ssl termination). Tested on iOS (react native app).

This is my haproxy config

```
global
    maxconn     50000
    log         127.0.0.1 local0
    user        haproxy
    chroot      /usr/share/haproxy
    pidfile     /run/haproxy.pid
    tune.ssl.default-dh-param 2048
    ssl-default-bind-ciphers ECDHE-ECDSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:ECDHE-RSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:DHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:ECDHE-ECDSA-DES-CBC3-SHA:ECDHE-RSA-DES-CBC3-SHA:EDH-RSA-DES-CBC3-SHA:AES128-GCM-SHA256:AES256-GCM-SHA384:AES128-SHA256:AES256-SHA256:AES128-SHA:AES256-SHA:DES-CBC3-SHA:!DSS
    ssl-default-bind-options no-sslv3
    daemon

defaults
    log global
    retries 3
    mode http
    stats enable
    stats uri /stats
    stats realm Haproxy\ Statistics
    stats auth xx:xx
    option forwardfor
    option http-server-close
    option httplog
    option dontlognull

frontend xxx_web
    bind *:443 ssl crt /etc/haproxy/certs/xxx.com.pem
    acl host_api_xxx hdr(host) -i api.xxx.com
    acl is_websocket hdr(Upgrade) -i websocket

    reqadd X-Forwarded-Port:\ 443
    reqadd X-Forwarded-Proto:\ https
    reqadd X-Forwarded-Scheme:\ https
    redirect scheme https if !{ ssl_fc }

    use_backend ws_xxx if is_websocket
    use_backend api_xxx if host_api_xxx

backend ws_xxx
    server ws_xxx 127.0.0.1:7777 check

backend api_xxx
    balance roundrobin
    reqadd X-Forwarded-Port:\ 443
    reqadd X-Forwarded-Proto:\ https
    reqadd X-Forwarded-Scheme:\ https
    server  api_xxx 127.0.0.1:7777 check # ssl verify none
```

Answer (score 0):

Changing the mode to "mode tcp" should help.